# Why am I getting a 405 error when my Django Stripe Checkout integration returns my success or cancel urls?

Tags: django, django-views

### Intro

I've been integrating Stripe Checkout into my django project, mainly following [this tutorial](https://justdjango.com/blog/django-stripe-payments-tutorial). Essentially, it involves a view with some forms that submit a request (SubscriptionsView) to another view you create (CreateCheckoutSessionView) that sends a properly configured API request to Stripe and redirects to a page hosted by Stripe. If the checkout works out, it redirects to a success URL you configure (SuccessView); if the user cancels, it redirects to a cancel URL you configure (CancelView).

### The problem

The external Stripe checkout page is working just fine; it's the success and cancel URLs that are not working.

Everything was working just fine earlier, but now (as I'm on my mobile hotspot; don't know if that would somehow affect things) it's throwing an HTTP 405 error every time Stripe redirects me to the success or cancel URLs.

#### Error in server readout

```
Method Not Allowed (GET): /subscribe/checkout/success/
Method Not Allowed: /subscribe/checkout/success/
[07/Jun/2023 05:00:47] "GET /subscribe/checkout/success/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

The two physical URLs in question are, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscribe/checkout/success/` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscribe/checkout/cancel/`

### Stuff I've checked

- I've checked to make sure my paths in my `urls.py` file are configured correctly
- I get the same error when I try to manually type in the two URLs that are throwing the 405.
- explicitly writing views to use get method instead of using TemplateView (see edit at very bottom)
- I tried writing the view even more simplistically and explicitly to tell it what to do when there was a GET request for the view (see edit at very bottom)

### My code

#### views.py

```
views.py

import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404

from .models import Product, Price
from scenario.models import Scenario
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

class SubscriptionsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "subscriptions/subscribe.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        product = Product.objects.get(stripe_product_id="xxxCensoredxxx")
        prices = Price.objects.filter(product=product)
        context = super(SubscriptionsView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            "product": product,
            "prices": prices
        })
        return context

class CreateCheckoutSessionView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        price = Price.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["pk"])
        domain = "https://fake.com"

        if settings.DEBUG:
            domain = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            line_items=[
                {
                    'price': price.stripe_price_id,
                    'quantity': 1,
                },
            ],
            mode='subscription',
            success_url=domain + '/subscribe/checkout/success/',
            cancel_url=domain + '/subscribe/checkout/cancel/',
        )
        return redirect(checkout_session.url)
    
class SuccessView(TemplateView):
    """View for if checkout was successfully completed"""
    template_name = "subscriptions/success.html"

class CancelView(TemplateView):
    """View for if checkout was cancelled"""
    template_name = "subscriptions/cancel.html"
```

#### project base urls.py

```
urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += [
    path('subscribe/', include('subscriptions.urls'))
]
```

#### subscriptions > urls.py

```
urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.SubscriptionsView.as_view(), name='subscribe'),
    path('checkout/<pk>/', views.CreateCheckoutSessionView.as_view(), name='checkout'),
    path('checkout/cancel/', views.CancelView.as_view(), name='cancel'),
    path('checkout/success/', views.SuccessView.as_view(), name='success'),
]
```

#### Subscriptions template

```
subscribe.html

{% extends "home.html" %}

{% block content %}

<section>
  <article>
    <h3>{{ product.name }}</h3>
    {% for price in prices %}
      <div>
        <h5>${{ price.get_display_price }}</h5>
        <form action="{% url 'checkout' price.id %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="price{{ price.pk }}">Number of accounts: 
          </label>
          <input type="number" name="accounts"
            id="price{{ price.pk }}" min="1" max="100" value="1"/>
          <button type="submit">Checkout</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </article>
</section>

{% endblock %}
```

### Edit:

#### More stuff I've tried

I've tried to rewrite the views (twice) that are throwing the error to explicitly use a get method instead of using the class-based TemplateView. This has not changed anything unfortunately; I'm getting the same 405 error (same django server readout messages).

#### new views.py

```
views.py

class SuccessView(View):
    """View for if checkout was successfully completed"""
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, "subscriptions/success.html")

class CancelView(View):
    """View for if checkout was cancelled"""
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, "subscriptions/cancel.html")
```

#### new views attempt #2

```
views.py
...
def cancel(request):
    """View for if checkout was cancelled"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "subscriptions/cancel.html")
    elif request.method == "POST":
        return render(request, "subscriptions/cancel.html")

def success(request):
    """View for if checkout was cancelled"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "subscriptions/success.html")
    elif request.method == "POST":
        return render(request, "subscriptions/success.html")
```

Comment: What is the physical URL? Looks like it should be: `.../subscribe/checkout/success`. What method are you hitting the view with, post or get? 405 in my experience means method (i.e  post or get) not allowed, which means they aren't defined

Comment: The physical URL is ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscribe/checkout/success/```

Comment: If you cannot figure this out I will provide a solution that calls get from your class, but that is simple to lookup

Comment: Try putting the url, 'checkout/<pk>' in the last position.

Comment: @Julkar9 There we go! That did it. Why is it that the order of my URL paths in urls.py was causing the 405 error?

Comment: wait I will add an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with these three urls
Django tries the url patterns in this order.

1. `checkout/<pk>/`,
2. `checkout/success/`,
3. `checkout/cancel/`

The problem is that `<pk>` can accept any string, so when you're redirecting to `checkout/success/`. Django's url resolver stops at `1. checkout/<pk>/`, and sets pk = 'success'. You can verify it by checking the view associated with `checkout/<pk>`

```
class CreateCheckoutSessionView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        print(pk)
        ...
```

So basically `checkout/success/` was redirecting to CreateCheckoutSessionView and because this view doesn't have a GET method you were getting the 405 Method not allowed.

This is a common problem that happens with re_paths, the solution is to keep paths with variables and re_paths at the end.

```
path('', views.SubscriptionsView.as_view(), name='subscribe'), name='checkout'),
path('checkout/cancel/', views.CancelView.as_view(), name='cancel'),
path('checkout/success/', views.SuccessView.as_view(), name='success'),
path('checkout/<pk>/', views.CreateCheckoutSessionView.as_view(),
```

Also if pk is supposed to be an integer, you can do `<int:pk>` to ensure pk only takes integer values. (Try re_path() for more complicated patterns)